# Show git commit logs only for a specific remote?

Tags: git

I'm using git 2.3.0. and trying to find 3 latest commits on a remote repository `myremote`.

```
$: git remote
origin
myremote
```

I would expect that the command

```
git log -3 --decorate --remotes=myremote
```

would achieve what i want. However, I can see the logs that are not strictly from `myremote`.

```
Example.
$: git remote
commit 63d8a59f6 (myremote/branch1)
...
commit 63d8a59f6 (myremote/branch2)
...
commit 63d8a59f6 (origin/branch3)
...
```

In the above example, I would expect not to see the anything from `origin`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a subtlety of the [functionality for `--remotes`](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-log):

```
   --remotes[=<pattern>]
       Pretend as if all the refs in refs/remotes are listed on the command line as
       <commit>.
```

Git **is** looking at the commit hashes for branches from `myremote`. But since your `origin/branch3` also is pointing to a hash from a `myremote` branch, it shows up in the log output.

Functionally

```
   git log --remotes=myremote
```

is the same as

```
   git log <hash1> <hash2> <hash3> ... <hashN>
```

where each hash is taken from the contents of the files in `.git/refs/remotes/myremote/`

Comment: So it's actually `--decorate` that's not acting as expected?

Comment: Well it was `--decorate` that caused your confusion, but the behavior is what's intended: `--remotes` **is** filtering the search to branches on the specified remote. But `--decorate` just finds all labels for the resulting set of commit hashes; it doesn't care what filters you may have used to obtain that set. Does that make sense?